# C language fscan doesnt stop

Tags: c, input, file-io

I have this code, and I want to take info from a text file and make an array of structs and save them in a new bin file. The thing is, that fscanf in while doesnt stop. the txt file is just like this "23A45 Lisboa 15.00 Coimbra 17.00 Aveiro 17.45 Porto 18.20"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TAM 20

struct paragem{
char local[TAM];
float hora;
};

int main()
{
FILE *f, *p;
struct paragem c;
char linha[TAM];

f = fopen("perc.txt", "rt");
if(f==NULL)
{
    printf("erro ao abrir ficheiro txt");
}
p = fopen("rota.bin", "wb");

if(p == NULL)
{
    printf("erro ao abrir ficheiro bin");
}
fscanf(f, "%s", &linha);
while(fscanf(f, " %s", &linha) != NULL )
{
    strcpy(c.local,linha);
    fscanf(f, " %f", &c.hora);
    fwrite(&c, sizeof(c), 2, p);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking `fscanf` against `NULL`? What is the reason behind that?

Comment: Well, im a newbie, I guess thats the reason ahah

Answer (score 3):

`fscanf` returns the number of items matched, or EOF (which is usually -1) on end-of-file.  So you want to say

```
while(fscanf(f, " %s", linha) == 1 )
```

Since NULL is 0, and since `fscanf` returns 1 on a successful match and -1 when it reaches end-of-file, that's probably explains why you had an infinite loop.

By the way, I also changed your `&linha` to just `linha`.  You generally need the `&` on the variables you hand to `scanf`, *except* when you're reading strings with `%s`.  In that case, since `linha` is an array, a pointer gets passed automatically, without your having to use `&`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that fixed the problem. If I were reading 2 strings I had to put == 2 , right?

Comment: Right.  2 for 2.

Comment: Btw, is there a way I could read a bin file like a text file, or at least see the info in a similar way?

Comment: @WalterPalma Lots of ways.  There are plenty of answers here on SO about it.  You might also see [this page](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx3b.html) and [this C FAQ list entry](http://c-faq.com/stdio/extconform.html).